# Android FragmentTransaction with fragment overlay

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a actionbar tab setup with fragments for each of the pages. (extended default example from wizard).

I'm attempting to create a new fragment and make it the current fragment, with the other hidden

```
ConfigDetailSectionFragment configDetailSectionFragment = new ConfigDetailSectionFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_main_config, configDetailSectionFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

the code shows the new fragment but seems it is transparent and I can see the fragment below.

i'm probably forgetting to do something...  what am i forgetting to do or am missing?

Comment: Have you tried to add a background color to your fragment?

Comment: that did it.  i figured it had to be hidden or something.  thanks for the easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an `android:background="#FFFFFF"` fixed the issue, per beworker.  Thanks!